# Getting the text from composite in eclipse using the SWTbot API

Tags: eclipse, swt, swtbot

I am trying to get the Text from a Composite in Eclipse using the SWTbot API.
I have Composite which contains Main Group and That Main Group Contains Child Groups.
The problem i am facing is i am not able to get the Text Inside the Composite, is there a way in Eclipse to get that Text.
I have attached the Image of my Composite, in which i want to get all the text like name,Min Version etc.
Please help, Its kind of blocker for my project.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but you can do it in this way:

```
public getContainedText(Control c) {
    return getContainedText(c, new ArrayList<String>());
}

private getContainedText(Control c, List<String> strings) {
    if (c instanceof Label) {
        strings.add(((Label) c).getText();
    } else if (c instanceof Text) {
        strings.add(((Text) c).getText();
    }
    // and so on for other control types you want to handle
    // and for text you are interested in.
    // Or as an approximation, use reflection to check if
    // c has getText method and call it, but this will miss
    // List, Combo, etc.

    if (c instanceof Composite) {
        for (Control child : ((Composite) c).getChildren()) {
            getContainedText(child, strings);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexey Thanks for the reply, i want to tell you that i am new to Eclipse Programming. So i have few doubts about the answer you have given.                                                                   As i am running my Eclipse in the SWTbot context so How am i going to get the Object of the Control class and the Composite object. Can you please elaborate your answer that i can understand.OR send some Example of that.                                                           Thanks In advance  !!!!

Comment: To find the controls you need in SWTBot, use http://download.eclipse.org/technology/swtbot/galileo/dev-build/apidocs/org/eclipse/swtbot/swt/finder/package-summary.html

Comment: Alexey, i have written some thing like this but No luck so Far.                                         SWTBot botFinder = new SWTBot();   
 Matcher<Widget> matcher =                                                          allOf(widgetOfType(Composite.class),inGroup("Product"));   
 Composite c = (Composite) botFinder.widget(matcher);   
 allTExt = getContainedText((Control) c, new ArrayList<String>());

Comment: I have ScrolledComosit in Location /Shell/-1//Shell/-1//Composite/0//Composite/0//Composite/0//Composite/1//Composite/2//ScrolledComposite/1//Composite/0//Group/0   "And                  I want to Pass the Object of the ScrolledComposite to the Control and then we can use the Method you have given.